# position relative vanished with height.?

Tags: css, css-position

Somehow this doesn't work in my main page index file i am making when trying to block it out for mobile first.
The properties are given, but as soon as i set position to relative it's now visible and somewhere in a corner.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .middle {
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(50%, 50%);
  }
  body {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
  }
  .hm_maincontainer {
    position: relative;
    height: 30%;
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: sienna;
  }
  .hm_mainspacer {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: purple;
  }
  .hm_buttoncontainer {
    position: relative;
    height: 30%;
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: salmon;
  }
  .hm_buttonblock {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  .hm_buttonspacer {
    background-color: red;
  }
  .hm_buttonimg {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  .hm_buttontext {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hm_maincontainer">
  <div class="hm_mainspacer middle">
    <div class="hm_main"></div>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="hm_buttoncontainer">
  <div class="hm_buttonblock">
    <div class="hm_buttonspacer">
      <div class="hm_buttonimg">

      </div>
      <div class="hm_buttontext">

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hm_buttonblock">
    <div class="hm_buttonspacer">
      <div class="hm_buttonimg">

      </div>
      <div class="hm_buttontext">

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hm_buttonblock">
    <div class="hm_buttonspacer">
      <div class="hm_buttonimg">

      </div>
      <div class="hm_buttontext">

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hm_buttonblock">
    <div class="hm_buttonspacer">
      <div class="hm_buttonimg">

      </div>
      <div class="hm_buttontext">

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

just block out the main content and buttons.
Main container will have a main image.
It will eventually overlap behind the buttons container, but first i want the blocks working main container above and button container below it.

all div children of the button and main container should be absolute within the relative containers.
Yet... they wont show up even though i have height set for them.

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: @paulie_D cvhecked the notes in the tutorial you mentioned and the containers should indeed be relative. 
and the underlaying absolute within the relative, so... What i made should work. did so with stuff i made i the past but cant wrap my head around why it wont work now. 
i have a height and width parameter set.

Comment: Fixed it. 
Without content i should not have used % apparently for width and height. but instead i used VH and VW.. now they are visible.